efficient way to read .csv file, extract 1x row at a time and write to a different output .csv file
I have a total of 690 .csv files. Within each .csv file are 250,000 rows. Each row 1,2,3...250k will be written to their output .csv file. I will have 250k .csv files and each of the 250k .csv files will have 690 rows.
OS is ubuntu. IVe tried a few methods. First was looping through each of the .csv files 1,2,3.... 690 and at each row, appending each row to the corresponding output.csv file. I also set this as a threaded operation using 16x cores. So at any given time there are 16x different .csv files open and they were appending row by row to 250k .csv files. When different threads were running I had the file output .csv file locked, then after append, released the lock to avoid appending clashes between different threads. This was very slow!. However the fastest way I found was by not using locks at all but i found that some of the rows that were being appended didnt do so correctly and its likely that there were clashes with multiple threads writing to the same file at the same time. In the end in each output .csv file, there are 690 rows.
Another method that I tried was just using a single thread and looping through each .csv file one at a time and writing each row to the output .csv file. This is very slow as well, its fast at first when on row 1:100 but getting into row 10,000 this operations is very slow.
I found it was faster, in Julia language to not open the file as a DataFrame as this was slow each time, it was faster to open() and use readline(). There is type inferences too with reading in as a dataframe. So Everything has been O(n). With the multi threaded approach, there was only efficiency when not using locks.... not using locks the operation took maybe 6 hours.
What i'm going to try now is indexing directly to the row numbers. I can try the dataframe approach again or using open(), position() to get the row byte offset and seek() to go directly to the row. If i can store all the byte row offsets per .csv file and directly go there, once there append that row to the output .csv file. I am looping through every 690 .csv file still. Then the rest of it is the writing operations to the disk row by row.... multiple cores all doing writing operations was very slow same with the locks.
If i'm on a single thread, indexing to each row in a .csv file and writing to .csv this might work.
Open to any other suggested approaches. Right now using julia language not against trying another language though.

Why not just do cat *.csv > output.csv ?

the total size of all 690 .csv files is 113.5gb. My memory on this computer is 64gb. Each file is between 175mb and 119mb.

AFAIK cat does not read the whole file in memory, just chunks, and it forward them on stdout, so it is fine. However, if CSV files have headers, it needs to be removed, except for the first file. All headers needs to be the same. I guess commands like tail, sed awk can do that well.

There is no need for multiple to make this fast if you do not parse the files (which is certainly not needed). 1 thread is often enough to saturate the storage device, or be close to. Note that SSD are fast up to a certain limit of data written due to the SLC cache. Beyond this limit they can be pretty slow. Sometimes slower than HDD for poor low-end SSDs. This should not take significantly more than 1h even on a mid-end HDD or a low-end SSD though (i.e. >=60MiB/s). 6h means a 10 MiB/s throughput which is very slow so the storage device is not the limit and the code is sub-optimal.

By the way, in Python, you can read big CSV files chunks by chunks, but honestly this is certainly not needed here and a sub-optimal approach.

Timing cached reads:   28706 MB in  2.00 seconds = 14376.98 MB/sec
Timing buffered disk reads: 340 MB in  3.00 seconds = 113.25 MB/sec
with the code I have right now it is more efficient to use a single thread operation. I pre-processed all 690 .csv files ahead of time, stored the byte offset for each row,then when processing each .csv file - I index directly to the needed row # and write this row the corresponding .csv output file- in about 30 mins, ive processed about 5k files so far. The pre processing has looped O(n) to get all the row index position. rest now is O(1)

@JérômeRichard interesting ! certainly seen I was limited by disk writing. I also tried to make some buffers of x size then lock, write and again multi threaded but didnt help.

I created 300 files of 180MB each I don't show full listing of them but see below.
Then I timed a cat *.txt to another disk.
Both disks are local attached Samsung 1TB SSD that are about 3-4 years old.
They are not SAN or high speed SSD and just in my workstation.
As you can see below this takes just over 2 minutes for 300 files creating an output.txt file of 55GB.
So if this approach takes hours on your system there is something wrong with throughput in your system.
See beklow I did not list all 300 files and the timings are also below.
Even if this is 300 files I do not think 700 files would be much different it would take less than 10 minutes at least.
-rwxr--r--+ 1 180M Jun  1 05:18 295.txt
-rwxr--r--+ 1 180M Jun  1 05:18 296.txt
-rwxr--r--+ 1 180M Jun  1 05:18 297.txt
-rwxr--r--+ 1 180M Jun  1 05:18 298.txt
-rwxr--r--+ 1 180M Jun  1 05:18 299.txt
-rwxr--r--+ 1 180M Jun  1 05:15 3.txt
-rwxr--r--+ 1 180M Jun  1 05:15 30.txt
-rwxr--r--+ 1 180M Jun  1 05:18 300.txt

$ time cat *.txt > ../../Games/output.txt
real    2m10.091s
user    0m0.343s
sys     0m10.905s


Within the 300 files are 250k rows. Each row is written or appended to a different .csv file. So it's a row by operation and at each row it's written to a different .csv file each time. In end have 250k final output .csv files. So need to do this row by row appending for all 300 files and every 250k row inside each of the 300 files.

I see two options? open 1x csv file at a time. Loop each row, append row to its own different output file. Procesd rows 1 to 250k. Go to next .csv file. Or process row 1 and loop through each .csv file appending to dame .csv file. Then go to row 2, loop through all .csv files appending row 2 row same .csv file. I got it done in about 6 hours.. created row index (byte offset, start of each row) for each .csv then I indexed each row in each .csv file and appended each row to its .csv file. That ended being o(1) access within each .csv. helps in later rows, don't need to loop all to get to each.
